# Git Desktop Error on MAC when click on "Sync"

Tags: xcode, git, macos, github

Stuck due to following error for Git Desktop application.

> 2018-06-08 12:10:11.769 GitHub Desktop Login[885:31180] AskPass with
>   arguments: (
>       "/var/folders/b0/ywryc75n5n5bj07zlfpnjxt00000gn/T/AppTranslocation/4F43D775-9B61-4C45-92F8-F30F0A572114/d/GitHub
>   Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/GitHub Desktop Login",
>       "Username for 'http://myserver': " )
>
> 2018-06-08 12:10:11.824 GitHub Desktop Login[885:31180] Error reading attributes
>   for password: OSStatus 1278174049 2018-06-08 12:10:11.845 GitHub
>   Desktop Login[886:31248] AskPass with arguments: (
>       "/var/folders/b0/ywryc75n5n5bj07zlfpnjxt00000gn/T/AppTranslocation/4F43D775-9B61-4C45-92F8-F30F0A572114/d/GitHub
>   Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/GitHub Desktop Login",
>       "Password for 'http://myserver': " ) 2018-06-08 12:10:11.846 GitHub Desktop Login[886:31248] 
>   *** Assertion
>   failure in -[GHAskPassKeychainAssistant
>   storedUsernameAndPasswordForURL:shouldDelete:],
>   /Users/joshaber/Documents/Development/GitHub/Mac/Classes/GHAskPassKeychainAssistant.m:165
>   2018-06-08 12:10:11.848 GitHub Desktop Login[886:31248] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not
>   satisfying: URL != nil'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2ee826bb __exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x00007fff5659e942 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff2ee882a2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98    3
>   Foundation                          0x00007fff30fc0340
>   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193     4
>   GitHub Desktop Login                0x0000000101762597
>   -[GHAskPassKeychainAssistant storedUsernameAndPasswordForURL:shouldDelete:] + 240     5   GitHub
>   Desktop Login                0x00000001017605f6 -[GHAskPass
>   responseForPromptType:URLString:] + 158   6   GitHub Desktop Login
>   0x00000001017611c5 -[GHAskPass responseForArguments:] + 356   7
>   GitHub Desktop Login                0x000000010175faba main + 174     8
>   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff571b5015 start + 1 )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException error:
>   /private/var/folders/b0/ywryc75n5n5bj07zlfpnjxt00000gn/T/AppTranslocation/4F43D775-9B61-4C45-92F8-F30F0A572114/d/GitHub
>   Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/GitHub Desktop Login died of signal 6
>   error: unable to read askpass response from
>   '/private/var/folders/b0/ywryc75n5n5bj07zlfpnjxt00000gn/T/AppTranslocation/4F43D775-9B61-4C45-92F8-F30F0A572114/d/GitHub
>   Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/GitHub Desktop Login' fatal: could not read
>   Password for 'http://myserver': Device not
>   configured  (128)

I put password in keychain correctly. Any help will much appreciated.

Comment: Git desktop? Do you mean github desktop?

Comment: @evolutionxbox. Yes

Comment: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: URL != nil' " The URL doesn't seem valid (escape percent characters? extra space ?"). It doesn't seem to be related to Keychain, but URL instead.